# How to extend user defined interface with an already defined interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a typescript lambda function which accepts the parameter `details`.

In my current code I already have a defined interface `APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters`. Since this details (query string) have some keys which I want to type define but I also want to use `APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters` how should I do that.

**Please note: I want to type safe the query string parameters which are coming as request parameters, for those values I am trying to define a type.**

I tried something like this

```
interface detailsProps extends APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters {
  approve: string,
  name: string
  token: string
}


async function trial(
  actionDetails: actionDetailsProps
) {
...
```

But when I try to call this function it says Argument of type `'APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters' is not assignable to parameter of type 'detailsProps'.`

```
export async function main(
  event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
  try {
    const abc =
      event.queryStringParameters!.xxxxx;

    await trial(event.queryStringParameters!); //error
    return {
      statusCode: 301,
      headers: {
        Location: xxxxx!,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "oh no",
      }),
      statusCode: 502,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told Typescript that the `trial` function's parameter must be a type with `approve`, `name`, and `token` keys.  But a `APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters` type, which is the [type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b48aca68552aa149abffff688ec5df7b7905301e/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts#L113) of `event.queryStringParameters` is not defined as definitely having these three keys.  Might have them.  Might not.

There are several ways to satisfy the compiler.  Hare are two options.

**Solution 1:** Define a new type to narrow the `event` type.  Explicitly tell Typescript to expect the 3 custom key-value pairs in the parameters:

```js
interface MyProxyEvent extends APIGatewayProxyEventV2 {
    queryStringParameters: detailsProps // note: the convention is to capitalize type definitions!
}

export async function main(
  event: MyProxyEvent
```

**Solution 2:**  Check for the existence of the 3 keys.  Typescript applys [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) and will take the hint.

```js
const params = event.queryStringParameters

if (!params?.approve || !params?.name || !params?.token)
    throw new error("Missing a required query parameter!")
```

Note that nothing you do here will prevent the Lambda being called without the correct query string parameters.  Typescript has your back at compile time, but not at run time.

Comment: Is it possible to type safe the keys? meaning can I make sure using typescript that the name of the keys ( key names)  passed as query string  will be always fixed for https://stackoverflow.com/q/75854201/13126651

Comment: @JatinMehrotra  Not at run time: see the answer's last paragraph.  Types are stripped out at compilation time.  If you are concerned the caller will not adhere to the event interface, consider something like Solution 2.  Solution 2 will work at run time, too, because it is vanilla JS.  It won't prevent your Lambda being executed with a non-conforming event, but you can gracefully handle failures.