# How to fix or type safe the name of the keys for object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a query string parameters object, This object has 3 keys with name  `a,b & c`.

I want to make sure that whenever a user passed query string parameters it should only contain keys name as `a, b and c` . If user passed d = 'some value', typescript should raise an error

```
enum queryStringParameters {
  a= 'a',
  b='b',
  c='c'
}

const actionDetails = {
      [queryStringParameters.a]: event.queryStringParameters!.qs1
      [queryStringParameters.b]: event.queryStringParameters!.qs2
       [queryStringParameters.c]: event.queryStringParameters!.qs3
    }
```

is there a way to fix the name of the keys of the object even better If I can fix the type too

Comment: Do you mean addig a `[queryStringParameters.d]: 'some value'` to the `actionDetails` object should raise a TS error?

Comment: Yes, i just want to fix the key names which are being passed  as query string parameters. If any key is passed typescript should raise an error

Comment: I tried that and TS does throw an error: `Property 'd' does not exist on type 'typeof queryStringParameters'.`

Comment: Is there a way i can fix the type of a  b and c to string?

Comment: Their type is already string: `console.log(typeof queryStringParameters.b) // string`

Comment: I am sorry there is a problem in understanding. I want to make sure the object  being passed by user in the object, it's key should be either a b or c and nothing else

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Can you show an example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: TypeScript can verify the consistency of a code base, it can't verify that an interface contract is being fulfilled with an external system (in your case an HTTP client)

Comment: Please [edit] the code in the question to be a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when others paste it into their own IDEs.  Right now `event` isn't defined so I get errors unrelated to your question, and it's not clear from that snippet where there should and shouldn't be compiler errors.  *Maybe* you're looking for the `satisfies` operator as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQRlvN), but I had to make a bunch of guesses and it would be best if such guesswork were not required.

Comment: Sorry for my poorly worded question,The event is coming from api gateway as described in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75852824/13126651

Comment: It would be best if you [edit] the code in the question to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't require navigating to other pages to see.  We should be able to copy and paste it from here and immediately get to work.  The harder it is for us to do that, the less likely it is that you'll get a useful answer.